# duplicate title tags?

Tags: html, css

Hi i am trying to style a title tag it works but it is coming up in the browser twice the one i styled and the preset  one as well.

any ideas ?  here's my code

Thanks all.

```
<a href="contact.php" class="test" title="CONTACT US!"></a>

a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right:23%;
  top: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*z-index: 20px;*/
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
}
```

Comment: The important thing to note is that it's not a **tag**, but rather an **attribute** - hence why it can't be styled. @Guffa has a very good answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't style the title, as it's not an element.

Each browser handles the title attribute in their own way, it can either show it on hover, not show it, or do something completely different...

What the code does is to create additional content that is shown, and that doesn't stop what the browser normally does with the title.

If you don't want the browser to show the title, don't use the title attribute. Use some other attribute that you know that the browser doesn't show.

Comment: can i not style it with Css3 ?

Comment: @MartinPalmer follow Guffa's suggestion and use a different attribute, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/csXQV/

Comment: @MartinPalmer: No, you can't. How the browsers show the title is still not standardised, there is no element that you can style. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-title-attribute

Comment: @jackjoe cheers never seen the data-title att before will remember it !

Comment: @MartinPalmer: Note: There isn't a special `data-title` attribute, you can use whatever you want, like `data-showmeonhoverplease`.

Comment: @Guffa i see so its basically just a variable

Comment: @MartinPalmer: Exactly, the `data-` prefixed attributes were added so that you can safely add "dead weight" attributes in the tags.